# Android running within Virtual Box can't reach the Internet

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, android, iptables

I'm running Android within Virtual Box and I'm trying to configure NAT in the host machine (Ubuntu Linux) so that the VM has access to the Internet.

In the Android guest I did:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.99.100
ip route add default via 192.168.99.1
```

Below is the current configuration taken from a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, when I try to ping 8.8.8.8 I get the error "connect: Network is unreachable". However, there is a default gateway set and the IP address is the proper one: in the host machine, the vboxnet0 interface is 192.168.99.1 (which in this case I will make act as a router).

Here is a screenshot with the VirtualBox network configuration:

[image]

I know I have to deal with iptables to make one net reach the other through the host machine, but I can't get there until I fix the issue described above (network unreachable).

Comment: You may wish to consider adding which virtual networking mode you are using for VirtualBox.

Comment: @Anaksunaman just attached a screenshot with the network configuration: host-only adapter, vboxnet0